# Default Navigation Bar Tabs by profile

Tags: lightning-apps, tab, navigation

I want to set the Default Tabs for one single app on a Profile Basis.

Ex:

> Sales Reps would have: Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, Tasks
>
> Sales Exec would have: Account, Contacts, Reports
>
> Sales Director would have: Accounts, Dashboard, Reports

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: All of these users having same profile?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion1:

If all users(`Sales Reps, Sales Exec & Sales Director`) have the same profile then update the `tab setting` to `Default Off` at profile level for the objects (Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, Tasks, Reports & Dashboards).

Create permission set with tab setting with `available & visible` check boxes enabled for each object and Assign it to the respective user.

In this case you need to create 3 permission sets.

Suggestion2:

If all users(`Sales Reps, Sales Exec & Sales Director`) have the different profile then update the `tab setting` to `Default Off` at profile level for the objects (Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, Tasks, Reports & Dashboards).

Example:
Sales Reps profile level you need to change the `tab setting` to `Default Off` for the objects (Reports & Dashboards)

Sales Exec profile level you need to change the `tab setting` to `Default Off` for the objects (Opportunities, Tasks, & Dashboards).

Sales Director profile level you need to change the `tab setting` to `Default Off` for the objects (Opportunities, Tasks, & contacts).